# Fontspec is giving me some absurd error

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, unicode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum,xltxtra}
\begin{document}
This is test
\end{document}
```

I get an error like this `"Missing \endcsname inserted....\UnicodeEncodingName {}{"007E}"`.

### Addendum

It is also printing a tilde(~) at the top of the text, as seen here:

[image]

Relevant files can be found [here](https://www.odrive.com/s/e036c60b-d914-4ab6-8acb-6310b8b0114f-58bbacf9).

Comment: I don't get any errors using `xelatex` on an up-to-date system. Even with `lualatex`, the file compiles (though with a warning about not using `xltxtra` with LuaTeX). The file also does contain a 'line of text': `This is test`..?  Could you give some sense of the nature of your installation? E.g., add `\listfiles` to the preamble and post the relevant-seeming portions of the `.log`?

Comment: It is also printing a tild(~) at the top of the text. Look at the following picture (copies and pasted the above text to make sure i am not making a mistake)https://monosnap.com/file/16Io1NRFIpYgTxyoMg6S9eaTYF51LO.png

Comment: I'm afraid more information is needed (for me at least, since I cannot reproduce your error with the file you have provided).

Comment: All the three files, if you would like: https://www.odrive.com/s/e036c60b-d914-4ab6-8acb-6310b8b0114f-58bbacf9

Comment: almost certainly you have previously used `fmtutil` rather than `fmtutil-sys` so you are using an old format even after texlive updates the main formats.

Comment: as you see the error is not absurd. the log is correctly showing that you are using new files with an old format. (after the warning the actual errors are spurious, the warning warns that latex is incorrectly configured, and after that anything can go wrong)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking in your `.log` you will find

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
```

and a little later

```
Package: fontspec 2017/02/12 v2.6 Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

which gives the warning

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "tu-clash"
* 
* I have found the tuenc.def encoding definition file but the TU encoding is
* not defined by the LaTeX2e kernel; attempting to correct but you really
* should update to the latest version of LaTeX2e.
*************************************************
```

As this says, you have an updated `fontspec.def` (matching the LaTeX 2017/01/01 release), but have an older format. You can see that from the file version line

```
File: tuenc.def 2017/02/22 v2.0g Standard LaTeX file
```

I'm not clear how you've updated `fontspec` but missed the LaTeX kernel update, but it's not surprising that 'bad stuff happens' as the changes made were tricky and do need to match up.

Either update LaTeX (and rebuild your formats) or switch back to the earlier release of `fontspec`.

Comment: I am running the latest versions of both the Latex and the package. Packages are more often updated than the core Latex. So, this is expected. Plus, I updated the package after it started to give me the error.

Comment: @Dellu No, the latest version of LaTeX is `LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3`, and the `2017/01/01` release was put out in sync with `fontspec` (Will Robertson is part of the LaTeX team).

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Texlive (which is 2016: and texlive updates once in  a year, according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)--i don't get what you mentioned.

Comment: @Dellu TeXLive is updated continually, and many/most TeX systems download the updates regularly or on user request. In your case it seems that such an update was interrupted, hence the inconsistency.

Comment: @Dellu you probably have a local format somewhere which shadows the new one. This can happen if you once run fmtutil instead of fmtutil-sys. Run `kpsewhich --all -engine=xetex xelatex.fmt` on a command line to check.

Comment: http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html---the latest update is October 2016. I am removing all of my system and re-installing it.

Comment: @Dellu As I've already said, the version of `fontspec` you have is _newer_ than the LaTeX format you've got installed, and that is where the issue is. I think you've installed BasicTeX from your `.log`: you should be able to run `tlmgr` (or the GUI equivalent) to update everything you have installed.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the BasicTex: and installed the whole MacTex. It is working now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have this issue since this morning.  I ran the command you suggested, and it returns /usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt.  What do I do with this?  Must I rebuild from scratch :( . ?

Comment: @Tim try `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` see the comments here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358996/fontspec-warning-tu-clash. Or deinstall basictex and install a full mactex, for some reason only basictex users seems to have this problem.

Comment: sudo fmtutil-sys --all seems to fix everything for me